# How to force tags created with Meteor Tags and Selectize to be lowercase

Tags: meteor, tags, selectize.js

I'm using the excellent package [Meteor Tags](https://atmospherejs.com/patrickleet/tags) to implement tags, and I'm copying [an example UI with a Selectize input](https://gist.github.com/patrickleet/e1c7a05eca86f536e3d4). I've also copied another example [how to use a filter with Selectize to avoid duplicate tags](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/issues/796), this is great and means that if there is an existing tag "mytag", and I type "Mytag" in the select, "mytag" will be added to the document.

So far so good. The problem comes when I force all tags to be lowercase for consistency. I have replaced this line from the Meteor Tags example:

```
Patterns.addTag(input, {_id: that.data._id});
```

with this:

```
Patterns.addTag(input.toLowerCase(), {_id: that.data._id});
```

Now if I type "Mytag" into the select, and hit Enter, then the text "Mytag" remains in the input, and "mytag" is not shown in the list of selected tags.

What I want to happen is for the input to be cleared and "mytag" added to the list of tags in the select, just as though I had typed "mytag" and hit Enter.

If I refresh the page, "mytag" IS displayed as a tag, so I know that the tag "mytag" is in fact being added to my document. However I can't find any way to make the selectize input update itself without refreshing the page. I've tried all the methods I can find from the [API docs](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md) without success. Any ideas?

Here is my full js code:

```
Template.tagInput.rendered = function () {
  var that = this;
  this.$('.tag-input').selectize({
    valueField: 'name',
    labelField: 'name',
    searchField: ['name'],
    create: function(input, cb) {
      console.log('create tag: ', input)
      Patterns.addTag(input.toLowerCase(), {_id: that.data._id});
      var tag =  Meteor.tags.findOne({collection: 'patterns', name: input});

      if (cb) {
        cb(tag);
      } 

      return tag;
    },
    options: Meteor.tags.find().fetch({}),
    render: {
        item: function(item, escape) {
            return '<div>' +
              (item.name ? '<span class="name">' + escape(item.name) + '</span>' : '') +
            '</div>';
        },
        option: function(item, escape) {
            var name = item.name;
            var caption = item.nRefs;
            return '<div>' +
                '<span class="name">' + escape(name) + '</span>&nbsp;' +
                (caption ? '<span class="badge">(x' + escape(caption) + ')</span>' : '') +
            '</div>';
        }
    },
    onItemAdd: function(value, $item) {
      console.log('add tag: ', value);
      Patterns.addTag(value, {_id: that.data._id});
    },
    onItemRemove: function(value) {
      console.log('remove tag: ', value);
      Patterns.removeTag(value, {_id: that.data._id});
    },
    createFilter: function (value)
  {
    // don't differentiate on case
    // https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/issues/796
    for (var optValue in this.options)
    {
      var name = this.options[optValue].name; // Property defined by labelField
      if (name.toLowerCase() === value.toLowerCase() && name !== value)
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
  });
};
```

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution ?

Comment: No, sadly I didn't. I had to accept tags may be any case.